# Excel : calculating average within a group

Tags: excel, ms-office

[image]

I'm working with excel 2016. I have some unstructured data as in the screenshot. I would like to group the rows by zip code , then calculate the average of all the values in each zip code. I'm pretty new to excel. Is there a function or group of functions which can do this?

Comment: You could structure your unstructured data and make it into a pivot table (in which case the functionality that you seek is built-in). You should also be able to do it with the `AVERAGEIF` function (at least for the calculating average by zipcode part goes).

Comment: Have you looked at averageif()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your table of data, to determine the `zip avg price/acre` you can do a weighted average.

- for each zip, divide the total sales price by the total acreage

I changed the data into a **Table** so as to be able to use structured references; but you can change that to regular addressing if you prefer.

The formula for doing the weighted average:

```
 =SUMIF([ZIP],[@ZIP],[price])/SUMIF([ZIP],[@ZIP],[acres])
```

[image]

*Note that if you calculated the average of the price/acre for each zip code, you would be computing the **Avg Price/Acre/Sale**, not the **Avg Price/Acre**. For zips with multiple sales, the difference can be substantial*

```
=AVERAGEIF([ZIP],[@ZIP],[Price/Acre])
```

[image]

If you just want to show the zip and the avg price/acre, you can use a Pivot Table:

- Drag zip => rows area
- Create a `Calculated Field` with the formula `=Sum(price)/Sum(acres)` and  drag that to the Values area

[image]

And, of course, if you should want the avg price/acre/sale, drag the Price/Acre to the Values area, and choose to summarize by average.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between [ZIP] and [@ZIP] ?